A way to automatically recreate pod on CreateContainerError
In my K8S cluster there is a occasional issue of pods getting stuck in "CreateContainerError" state without any errors or problems. Every time the problem is fixed simply by deleting stuck pod and letting deployment recreate it. I suspect some NFS PVC issue, but this problem occurs only once every 3-4 months making debugging very difficult.
The real problem is that when this happens the only way to bring back affected service is to manually delete this pod. I tried to find a way to do it according to the k8s philosophy, but apparently there is no option to force deployment to recreate pod.
My question is: is there a way or tool to automate recreating pods in "CreateContainerError" state when it happens?

I ended up creating an alertmanager alert for kube_pod_container_status_waiting_reason{reason="CreateContainerError"} > 0 and using a webhook to manually search and delete all pods with such status in a
jenkins shell script job
